# Why is Internet Explorer stretching the image?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a HTML file with following text.

```
<div id="id1" style="max-height: 100px; min-width: 100px;">
    <div align ="center" id="id3">
        <div id="id2" style="height: 100px; max-width: 364px;">        
            <img src="http://www.file-extensions.org/imgs/articles/4/369/windows-10.png" height=100%; width=100%; />        
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

When I open it Firefox, chrome or IE 9 or above then it displays as expected. But when I open it in IE8 or below then it is fully stretched to the width of the screen. If I remove the `width=100%` then it works fine.

**Two questions:**

- Why it works as expected in latest Firefox, chrome versions and IE 9 or above? Is that a known bug/issue in IE8? If yes then what is it?
- How to fix it's display in IE8 browser without changing the HTML itself i.e. I cannot remove the `width=100%` attribute.

Comment: FYI: there is no such thing as `float:center`

Comment: ok thanks, let me remove it and try.

Comment: can you simplify your HTML markup?

Comment: I removed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: How do you expect the image to display, actually?

Comment: The image width should NOT be same as the width of the browser. It should be 364px max. That's how it is on firefox and chrome. But on IE 8 it's like 1000px wide (width of browser).

Comment: Actually I resolved it by putting <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of the document. So this went against what I mentioned in the question i.e. html should be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified solution based on your comments above

```css
div {
    min-width: 100px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    max-width:364px;
}
img {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    display:block /*fix inline img gap*/
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
    <img src="http://www.file-extensions.org/imgs/articles/4/369/windows-10.png" />
</div>
```